# Do you know how can I see any image of graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

If exist homepage or method, please tell me.

I want see some image of graph like $y=x^2\sin\left(1/x\right)$ or $y=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$.

Of course, I know that they are not complex, but I want to see it sketched lovely.

I know mathematica, but I don't have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of options online if you google. One nice alternative is Wolfram Alpha. For one of the plots you want, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bx%5E2%20Sin%5Bx%5D,%20%7Bx,0,10%7D%5D). It should be straightforward to generalise.

Comment: Thank you! your site is really good!!!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a plot of the function $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$. Note that since $$|\sin(1/x)|\leq 1$$ so $$-x^2\leq f(x)\leq x^2$$ You see this squeezed function between two blue ones.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!! It's nice image!

Comment: Nice image, indeed! +1